# Row Ordering / positioning on Bootstrap 3

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

I just start to use this framework Bootstrap 3 and i am trying to change the order of a row.

On css flexbox you can change the order of flex object by adding the order : 1,2 and more to different elements.

Is it possible to do that on a row in bootstrap?

I have a logo image and i want that on a mobile site it will be at the top of the page, 
And In a desktop site it will be after a few rows in the top.

Comment: Can you please post some code to show where exactly are you stuck and what doesn't work? 
P.S. welcome to the SO :)

Answer (score 2):

There is nothing that I know of in Bootstrap that will allow for that type of change vertically. So your best option would probably to be to duplicate the logo in the places where you want it, then use Bootstrap's [responsive utilities](http://getbootstrap.com/css/#responsive-utilities) to control if they are visible based on screen size.

Working example: http://bootply.com/91992

Comment: the problem is that i have not just the image to reposition. and it will be problem to have so much of a duplicate content.

Comment: Can you add some code to your question so we can get a handle on what exactly you are talking about?

Answer (score 0):

No, at least not conveniently with CSS alone. You'd have to use jQuery (or just JavaScript). A better approach might be to create duplicate elements and show/hide with media queries.